# ssh and sudo: How to ask for sudo password in an ssh script processing stdin

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have a script running on a remote host through ssh, processing stdin from the host.

That is the script does something like this (to simplify):

```
cat $TARBALL | ssh $REMOTE 'tar -x -C -f - && reboot'
```

This work fine if I use root as the ssh user, but if I don't have root access on the REMOTE, I want to execute the command with sudo instead, eg:

```
cat $TARBALL | ssh $REMOTE 'sudo tar -x -C -f - && sudo reboot'
```

I would want the user to be asked the password interactively here, but sudo can't get the password in that situation.

How can I somehow instruct sudo to ask for the password on the local terminal? Seems like the -A option could enable this, but I can't figure what askpass program I might need in this case.

Comment: ssh $HOST 'sudo -S ls | grep my_file'

Answer (score -1):

When you have to deal with passwords prompts on standart input, the recommanded Unix way is to use the `expect(1)` tool which was made specially for that purpose.

Comment: How does expect help here? sudo won't have a prompt on stdout and stdin is used to provide other data